# Buttons gone after added swiperefreshlayout

Tags: android, listview, layout

I have a layout with listview and two buttons side by side at the bottom of the listview. Everything work fine until I have added the swiperefreshlayout for my listview.

My codes are as below.

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFF"
>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/search_bar"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/keyword_editText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_edit_text"
        android:hint="Keyword"
        android:textColorHint="@color/list_item_title"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:maxLines="1"/>


</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/search_bar"

    >

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/RsListView"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:divider="#D3D3D3"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/req_history_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Request History"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/request_history_button"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/apprv_history_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Approval History"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/approval_history_button"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_text_color"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Sorry for dumping my codes here as I can't figure out any other way for you guys to understand my code.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `LinearLayout` usually all children have even dimension according to orientation. However, when you would like one child to take a little amount of place and another to fill the rest, you might be interested in `layout_weight` parameter. If the child that should fill the space gets `android:layout_weight="1"` it will fill the space making a place for other views.

In order to see the buttons add `android:layout_weight="1"` to `SwipeRefreshLayout` and set `android:layout_height="0dp"`. That will make your buttons visible.

Comment: hi @R. Zagórski as i have my swiperefreshlayout before the linearlayout for my buttons why should i add weight="1" to my swiperefreshlayout? won't it be worse for my button to show?

Comment: Right now, the height of your SwipeRefreshLayout is match_parent, so it will occupy the entire LinearLayout and hide your buttons. When you add  layout_weight = 1 to your SwipeRefreshLayout, itmeans that it should occupy any free space that is remaining in your LinearLayout. So the buttons will be place first and they will get all the space that they need since they have a height of wrap_content, and then all the remaining space will be taken by the SwipeRefreshLayout.